# How to rescue a corrupt notebook?

Tags: notebooks

Something happened to my Notebook and most of the sections now look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to rescue this notebook?

It can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CaIhWSNNoT7zbLn0yPJXbE_gLXpHvshF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can open the notebook using plain text editor (it is a text file after all) and just look to see at least if all your code is all still there (but do not make any edits or changes, as you might make things worst).

Comment: There's an option in the File > Open dialog, parse and read entire notebook (or something like that). That might work, I think. It's been a long time since a notebook has done something like this. In line with @Nasser's warning, make a copy first. You could also read in the notebook into Mathematica and try manipulating it: `nb = NotebookOpen[file, Visible -> False]; nbExpr = NotebookGet[nb];`. A large notebook may be hard to manage, though.